Mongo compound index behaving differently
I have a compound mongo index where one of the fields is SerialNumber.
It runs faster when it has value like:
SerialV1_72:68:6b:ac:5e:30
SerialV1_85:75:a9:b1:d9:d7

It runs slow when it has value like:
serial_bdee115bb9f2
serial_aa1c2385e9f1


The index runs slower?
